# Is Action Cable the same thing as Faye?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, faye, actioncable

Implementing Web Sockets in my app I've become confused which gem is better. I found plenty of different opportunities, however, some are hard to distinct.

Finally, I've chosen Action Cable (a Rails 5 native part) and Faye (appeared earlier and became very popular).

But now I'm stuck - is Action Cable the same thing as Faye? Which are differences (if there's any)?

Comment: It is easier to vote down than answer, right?

Comment: I think the down votes was because the question is a little bit [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I think that's because people love questions like "What's the command for running a migration?" My question wasn't off-topic, however, it looked like at glance. At least I didn't want to be off-topic. I just wanted to get what's the difference _in further programming_ before integrating any of these gems.

Comment: Why it is off-topic??

Comment: @FelipeMaion People think I asked: "Which gem is better?". Nevertheless, it is a question about the difference between these gems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**From the Faye website:** *Faye is a publish-subscribe messaging system based on the Bayeux protocol. It provides message servers for Node.js and Ruby, and clients for use on the server and in all major web browsers.*

**From the ActionCable readme:** *Action Cable seamlessly integrates WebSockets with the rest of your Rails application. It allows for real-time features to be written in Ruby in the same style and form as the rest of your Rails application, while still being performant and scalable. It's a full-stack offering that provides both a client-side JavaScript framework and a server-side Ruby framework. You have access to your full domain model written with Active Record or your ORM of choice.*

---

Short answer is YES, both are pub/sub messaging system.

Long answer is NO, because faye is a low-level tool and ActionCable uses faye ([look here](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=faye)), al least some components.

But you always can get the same results using (maybe) different efforts building an application using faye or ActionCable. The big difference is Faye works as a rack-based component instead of rails-based component.

Comment: Future readers might want to know that ActionCable performs TERRIBLY. I ran into my own problems with it only after moving my work to a production environment, and it's literally so bad that it's unusable if you expect high traffic. As example, this post here describes a benchmark test involving 20,000 idle clients. ActionCable uses 3.5GB of memory, compared to other solutions, which are < 900MB https://medium.com/@leshchuk/from-action-to-any-1e8d863dd4cf